# MySQL in Docker on Ubuntu: Warning: World-writable config file is ignored

Tags: java, mysql, docker

In my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, I have: `!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` configed, and I think the `my.cnf` file in my `!includedir` directory should overide `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html.

But I got a `World-writable config file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/my.cnf is ignored` warning when restaring my mysql server, and confirmed that the config in that `my.cnf` file in my `!includedir` did not work. Why the warning happened, and how to make it work?

**Context:**

Ubuntu 16.04.3 in a Docker,mysql 5.7.22

**Note:**

I know that if my `cnf` file contains multiple dots if may not work:

https://serverfault.com/questions/918530/mysql-includedir-not-working

But I don't think I am hitting that issue.

Comment: Was the docker image created using your Dockerfile? Maybe in that you can `RUN chmod go-w /etc/mysql.conf.d/my.cnf` set the permissions more restrictively.

Comment: What is the permission of that file?

Comment: @danblack No,the docker image was created by the administrator.

Comment: @GenoChen with permission 777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your administrator to fix the permissions, upstream is fine:

```
$ docker run mysql find /etc/mysql -ls
Unable to find image 'mysql:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/mysql
a5a6f2f73cd8: Pull complete 
936836019e67: Pull complete 
283fa4c95fb4: Pull complete 
1f212fb371f9: Pull complete 
e2ae0d063e89: Pull complete 
5ed0ae805b65: Pull complete 
0283dc49ef4e: Pull complete 
a7e1170b4fdb: Pull complete 
88918a9e4742: Pull complete 
241282fa67c2: Pull complete 
b0fecf619210: Pull complete 
bebf9f901dcc: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:b7f7479f0a2e7a3f4ce008329572f3497075dc000d8b89bac3134b0fb0288de8
Status: Downloaded newer image for mysql:latest
  4225047      0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root           57 Nov 16 01:12 /etc/mysql
  6324293      0 drwxrwxr-x   2 root     root           41 Nov 16 01:10 /etc/mysql/conf.d
  6324294      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1294 Oct  7 09:13 /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
  6324308      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root           43 Nov 16 01:10 /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
  4225049      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         1469 Oct  7 09:13 /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
  4225048      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 root     root         1174 Nov 16 01:10 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 6):

Change permissions to 0444:

`chmod 0444 my.cnf`

And then mount it into `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`:

```yaml
volumes:
    # Set mysql extra config:
    - my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning is actually saying: `world writable` config files will be ignored. I really should read carefully about the messages.

Changing the permision to 775(or 755) fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

root@c70ab714446b:/# chmod 0444 /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why would the command you posted be useful on Windows? `chmod` is a Unix command. Also, can you [edit] your question and explain what that command does? Code-only answers tend to not do well as they encourage people to blindly copy some stuff from the web instead of learning something. See [answer].

Comment: The OP is on Linux - Context:

Ubuntu 16.04.3 in a Docker,mysql 5.7.22